# Will my app run on android 4.0 if I use JDK 8

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8

My android studio project uses the embedded JDK which is version 8 by default im wondering will my app still run on android 4.0 and 5.0 devices ?

Comment: did you tried once running it?

Comment: no, I have not, android studio recommends I use the embedded jdk that comes with android studio and it is version 8

Comment: according to me the app will definitely run with JDK 8 run it

Comment: ok thanks very much ! also do you know what this means "you can use JDK 8, but compile with JDK 7 feature set." ? i couldn't understand it that good in these docs im reading

Comment: it says "Why do you need JDK 6 ? only for older versions ? whats your preferred minSDK? if you start with API 19 you have a rate of 95%, So you can use JDK 8, but compile with JDK 7 feature set."

Comment: i just wasn't sure what it meant by "compile with JDK 7 feature set" how is it possible to use JDK 8 during development but then compile with JDK 7 if there 2 different jdks

Comment: howdy bro? you need help?

Comment: No bro everythings good, thanks for asking though!

Comment: Lol I was waiting for your comment :p

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal can you check this out bro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622244/using-a-different-ndk-version

Comment: read out the comment section on your question asked. The second comment on your post note it down as because if you want to do something you have to try first.

Comment: hi mate! how are you?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal how do you do private message on here I forgot ?

Comment: go to my profile and drop me a linkedin mail

Comment: I don't got linkedin send me a message like last time on stackoverflow

Comment: join the chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192447/room-for-harshit-agrawal-and-izzyjm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app will definitely run with JDK 8 run it.

Android Studio 3.0 and later supports all Java 7 language features and a subset of Java 8 language features that vary by platform version.

Android Studio provides built-in support for using certain Java 8 language features and third-party libraries that use them.

**Note:**

> When developing apps for Android, using Java 8 language features is
>   optional. You can keep your project's source and target compatibility
>   values set to Java 7, but you still need to compile using JDK 8.

And about your minSDK comment "whats your preferred minSDK? if you start with API 19 you have a rate of 95%"->

minSdk is required to set the minimum api level run environment(android OS version) to the application. If you choose minSdk the minimum possible you can target max number of devices.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use JDK8 to compile your Android app there is no problem with it, you can easily set compatibility to Java 6/7 and there won't be any issues.

If you want to use Java 8 language features it all depends on the `mindSdkVersion` that you have set up. You can freely use:
- lambda expressions
- method references
- default and static methods in interfaces
- repeating annotations

Java 8 API is available from API level 24 unfortunately in your case you won't be able to use any Stream API and such.

For more information please check:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Comment: im using the embeddedJDK (8) thats set by default with Android Studio 3.0, does this mean my project is automatically built and also compiled with this version ? I tried looking for project settings that show the build and compiled version but can't find it